# Question regarding Samsung firmware

Tags: samsung, root-access, samsung-one-ui

Recently I have been messing with my phone's stock firmware, and some files caught my attention, I couldn't find anything about them on Google so I came to ask here.
The files in questions are:

```
/system/lib64/libgui.so   
/system/lib/libgui.so   
/system/bin/surfaceflinger
```

Comment: [surfaceflinger](https://source.android.com/docs/core/graphics/surfaceflinger-windowmanager)